# Partial Regexp Match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long regex that is generated to match URLs like

```
/^\/([^\/.?]+)(?:\/([^\/.?]+)(?:\/([^\/.?]+)(?:\.([^\/.?]+))?)?)?$/
```

Would match:

```
/foo/bar/1.html
```

as `['foo', 'bar', '1', 'html']`

In Javascript I would like to get the parts that match as the user types the url (like a typeahead). For example if they typed:

```
/foo
```

It would tell me that `/foo` was matched, but the whole regexp hasn't been satisfied. Ruby can return an array with only the matching partial elements like : `['foo', nil, nil, nil]` is this possible, or easy to do in Javascript?

Comment: You could add a `?` after every one of your groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@minitech basically gave half the answer: use `?` after each group, and then you'll be able to match the regex even if they're missing.  Once you can do that, then just check the groups of the regex result to see which bits have been matched and which haven't.

For example:

```
/^\/([^\/.?]+)?(?:\/([^\/.?]+)?(?:\/([^\/.?]+)?(?:\.([^\/.?]+))?)?)?$/.exec('/ab/c')
```

Would return:

```
["/ab:c", "ab:c", "c", undefined, undefined]
```

By checking and seeing that the fourth value returned is undefined, you could then figure out which chunks were/were not entered.

As a side note, if you're going to be working lots of regexs like this, you can easily lose your sanity just trying to keep track of which group is which.  For this reason I strongly recommend using "named group" regular expressions.  These are otherwise normal regular expressions that you can create if you use the XRegxp library (http://xregexp.com/), like so:

```
var result = XRegExp.exec('/ab/c', /^\/(?<fooPart>[^\/.?]+)?(?<barPart>?:\/([^\/.?]+)?(?:\/([^\/.?]+)?(?:\.([^\/.?]+))?)?)?$/)
var fooPart = result.fooPart
```

That library also has other handy features like comments that can similarly help keep regular expression under control.  If you're only using this one regex it's probably overkill, but if you're doing lots of JS regexp work I can't recommend that library enough.

Comment: Can this be done without modifying the regex, just using JS? Or would that just be asking for pain?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this".  If you mean the XRegexp library, it works with native JS regular expressions, so you can start using it with minimal "pain".  If you meant adding the `?` to your regular expression ... no I don't think it's possible to modify a regular expression in place.  However, you could always build a new one based on the old one using `oldregex.source` as a basis (eg. `new RegExp(oldregex.source.replace(')', ')?'))`..